# How to understand and fix LogCat below

Tags: android

I really wonder why my application is working as usual buy LogCat generated error as below:

```
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837): Activity kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_hard_4 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a3d130 that was originally added here
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_hard_4 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a3d130 that was originally added here
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:288)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_hard_4.onBackPressed(animal_q_hard_4.java:5462)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2050)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2485)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2280)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1649)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRoot.java:2895)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2868)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2048)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do appreciated for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850597/2910492): "You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.". It comes down to the problem that after the activity is finished (either by calling `finish()` or using the back button (which is the case here)), you try to show a dialog on top of the activity, which does not exist anymore. That is not possible.

Comment: @jefferey Klardie, I understand what you mean. Wait I am testing it again.

Comment: @Jefferey Klardie, It's working fine now. Thank you so much. The problem is because I put this: i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Dialog was started while Activity was changing. I.e. the window of the correct activity is not there when Dialog is to be displayed. Dialog is tied to the window of activity which started it.

Comment: A, I am testing it again. Thanks You!

Answer (score 1):

The line I would look at is:

`12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837):   at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_hard_4.onBackPressed(animal_q_hard_4.java:5462)`

Most likely something in the function is causing the error. Try commenting the entire function and see if you still experience it.

Comment: I am testing again. Thanks q

Answer (score 1):

This will show you the exception..

```
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837): Activity kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_hard_4 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a3d130 that was originally added here
12-04 22:10:56.659: E/WindowManager(837): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_hard_4 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40a3d130 that was originally added here
```

This is because you are displaying a dialog in a `Activity`..but here the `Activity` already finished so its giving you the exception..